# spring integration inboundChannelAdapter produce more than one message at a time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I tried to define an InboundChannelAdapter to read messages from a queue API (azure in this case). The native approach looks like this:

```
  @Bean
  @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "myChannelExample",
                         poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000",
                                          maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
  public MessageSource<QueueMessage> queueReadingMessageSource() {
      return wrapMessage(queueClient.readMessage())
  }
```

This works as expected - but I was wondering it there is a more efficient way to define an adapter which would be able to read multiple (maxMessagesPerPoll>1) messages at once from the message source? Is there a messageSource interface which allows returning a list of messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return a message with a `List<QueueSource>` payload and add a splitter downstream.